# JQuery autocomplete not working until after page refresh and/or a random event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autosave

Apologies for the title.

I have a page using two scripts, both acting upon the same form.

This is an autosave script (as there is a lot of typing on the form, I don't want users to lose data).

```
<script rel="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.post("autosave.php", "json");
        setInterval(function () {
            $.post("autosave.php", $("form").serialize());
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

Which works well.  autosave.php is nothing more than a simple db query updating the various fields from the POST data its getting from the form.

I am also using an autocomplete script for the email field in my form.

```
<script rel="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = <?php include('view-job-q-em-search.php'); ?>;
        $("#sendy_to").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            autoFocus:true
        });
    });
</script>
```

This also works well, the PHP script in this again is just a simple db query returning a json array.

However, they don't work well together, well they do, to a fashion.

Interestingly if I type even so much as a single character into one of the text boxes on the form, then refresh, the autocomplete starts working, but it wont when the page loads for the first time.  It is like it is stuck waiting for the autosave to perform its first action before the autocompete kicks in.

I am versed enough in Jquery to make these things work, but not good enough yet to spot the anomaly's, so any help or ideas to make this work would be great.

I'm also using generic external scripts jquery.min, jquery,ui which are loaded at the start of the page in the `<head>`

Comment: Instead of triggering auto save functionality on time interval try to save that on `blur` event of any field. I think that will resolve the issue. There are also different way to handle auto save. You can define a variable for ex: `var isFormDirty = false;` and then when user edit something make that `true`. And that way trigger the auto save on `blur` event if and only if  `isFormDirty === true`. Hope you get some idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it (and without running too many tests), you're running your code in a synchronous way. What I mean is that this statement:

`var availableTags = <?php include('view-job-q-em-search.php'); ?>;`

is preventing the execution of the rest of the code since your server is parsing a PHP script.
Instead of including a script for your availableTags, use AJAX to request the tags
available, for example:

```
var availableTags;
$.get( "tags/getAvailable", function( data ) {
    availableTags = data;
    $("#sendy_to").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        autoFocus:true
    });
});
```

that should solve the issue. Could you elaborate on the contents of `view-job-q-em-search.php`?

Comment: Sure .... while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
   $dname_list[] = $row['sent_to'];
    }
    echo json_encode($dname_list);

Comment: @Stephen now I understand.. you're running a query in your PHP script, which prevents the rest of the code from executing by the time you refreshing the page. use AJAX instead as mentioned above^

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was a combination of two things.  Firstly, you were completly right, the call needed to be synchronous.

The biggest problem ...
Because I was autosaving every two seconds, as soon as I opened the form I was saving a blank row.  The query for the autocomplete was then trying to populate a json array with a blank entry and it didnt like it.

The workaround was to just add ...

```
$dname_list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if(!empty($row['sent_to'])){
        $dname_list[] = $row['sent_to'];
    }

}
echo json_encode($dname_list);
```

... the !empty clause into the query so that it didnt try and add empty rows to the json array.

Comment: Huh, I see now, great catch!